# What Nuget Package do I need for WinApplication.GetSecurityStrategy().RegisterXPOAdapterProviders();?

Tags: c#, nuget, xaf, xpo

I created a new Winforms Xaf Xpo standard security project with 21.2/5
Then I changed the framework of each project to be 4.7.2
Then I ran the upgrade wizard.
Then I tried to convert the project files to use Nuget with Package References.
However I get the following build errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'SecurityStrategy' does not contain a definition for 'RegisterXPOAdapterProviders' and no accessible extension method 'RegisterXPOAdapterProviders' accepting a first argument of type 'SecurityStrategy' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  DXXpo.Win   C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\DXXpo\DXXpo.Win\Program.cs  33  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SecuredObjectSpaceProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    DXXpo.Win   C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\DXXpo\DXXpo.Win\WinApplication.cs   20  Active
```

I tried drilling into another new project and I can see that RegisterXPOAdapterProviders has namespace DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security
I already have that installed as a NugetPackage.
I tried installing DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.Xpo but I get a message
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package DevExpress.ExpressApp.Persistent.Base. No packages exist with this id in source(s): DevExpressMy, nuget.org, SBDCommonFeed@Local DXXpo.Win   C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\DXXpo\DXXpo.Win\DXXpo.Win.csproj    1
```

There are no packages starting with DevExpress.ExpressApp.Persistent in the feed.

[image: Error message]

The docs are [here](https://docs.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/115912/installation/install-devexpress-controls-using-nuget-packages)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71107005/xaf-wizard-creates-21-2-3-project-when-21-2-5-is-installed) question is possibly related.

Comment: Have you updated any existing DevExpress packages first?

Comment: How do you mean? Package update is just to get newer packages for existing Nuget packages. I need to convert the references to use Nuget.

Comment: Well, the way I look at it is this: you're trying to install DevExpress.ExpressApp.Xpo, and that can't find a type that's presumably provided by DevExpress.ExpressApp. My conclusion is that you perhaps have an older version of DevExpress.ExpressApp that doesn't have that type, and while .NET is trying its best to make things work, it can't just made a type exist out of nowhere. Now, I haven't used DevExpress so I could be completely wrong here, but that's my hunch anyway.

Comment: I am using the latest version 21.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by including the package DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.Xpo